# Scala: Play: Action classes — import behavior changed from Play 2.4 to Play 2.8

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using Play 2.8.7, Scala 2.13.4.

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import play.mvc.Controller
import play.api.i18n.{I18nSupport, MessagesApi}
import javax.inject._

class Application @Inject() (
  val messagesApi: MessagesApi
) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  def greeting = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok("hello")
  }
}
```

**1.** I want to import `play.api.mvc.Results.Ok` — why is it only imported when I do `import play.api.mvc.Results._` but not when I only do `import play.api.mvc._`?
The latter used to work when I used Play 2.4.3 (Scala 2.11.11).

**2.** The compiler cannot resolve symbol "Action". Why is that...? I did `import play.api.mvc._`

**UPDATE:**

There was a suggestion to import `play.mvc.BaseController`.

It seems not to exist in `Play 2.8.7`.

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure this has nothing to do with the **Scala** version. You basically upgraded `4` minor versions of the **Play** framework, many things could have changed. I would recommend you to take a look at the changelogs and edit the tittle of this question so it because clearer.

Comment: The code is quite basic, so it's not like trying to upgrade it, it's more like writing it in 2.8 and then comparing it to 2.4... I did try to follow Play 2.8 documentation while writing it. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaActionsComposition What do you think a better title would be?

Comment: Something like _"Play: Result codes import change from 2.4 to 2.8"_.

Comment: Alright, updated.

Answer (score 2):

"Controller" is for Java, so you should use "play.mvc.BaseController" in Scala.

Q1 & Q2 both would be resolved if you are using "play.mvc.BaseController". " import play.api.mvc.Results._" is also unnecessary.

Comment: Actually, with Play 2.8.7 and `play.mvc.BaseController`, I am getting `type BaseController is not a member of package play.mvc`. When I try `play.api.mvc.BaseController` I am getting `Class 'Application' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member 'controllerComponents: ControllerComponents' in 'play.api.mvc.BaseControllerHelpers'`

Comment: Can you share the minimum project where you can reproduce the error?

Comment: I guess I can, but first take a look at the update I made to my question. Can you find `play.mvc.BaseController` in your copy of `Play 2.8.7`?

Comment: I'm sorry. It was typo'd. I'm looking at the sample project linked in the official documentation. The code is as follows :
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {

  def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
}

Comment: What is the link to that official documentation page you were looking at?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/NewApplication or 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/HelloWorldTutorial#Starting-the-project

Comment: Thanks for the links. So first, I have to inject the `ControllerComponents` stuff. Second, the class to extend is `play.api.mvc.BaseController`. Why is `import play.api._` not enough to import `play.api.mvc.BaseController`? Does `import` refer only to items at the root level of the location it points to?

Answer (score -1):

import `play.mvc.Controller` and `play.mvc.Result` and extends your class to `Controller`.

Example:

```
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class ClassName extends Controller { 

  //code

}
```